# Symfony Forms: How to save properties of related entity?

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony

I'm new to Symfony and have very basic question regarding forms and relations.

The goal is to build a form to save/ edit an object based on an entity which includes a property related to another entity. Unfortuanetely I have no idea how to define the fields in the buildForm method to save/ edit the properties of this related entity.

**Entity\Artist.php**

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="artist")
 * @UniqueEntity("name")
 */
class Artist {

    const THEMES_ENABLED = true;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=150, unique=true, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $name;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="ArtistBiography", mappedBy="artist")
     */
    private $artistBiography;

    // Getter & Setter ...        
}
```

**Entity\ArtistBiography.php**

```
**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="artist_biography")
 */
class ArtistBiography {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Artist", inversedBy="artistBiography")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="artist_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $artist;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=150, unique=false, nullable=false)
     */
    private $headline;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=150, nullable=false)
     */
    private $text;    

    // Getter & Setter ...

}
```

I use this custom FormType to render:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
//use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ArtistType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Entity\Artist',
        ));
    }
}
```

How can I add the Fields for the properties **'artistBiography.headline'** (TextType) and **'artistBiography.text'** (TextareaType)?

Comment: I think you need `ArtistBiographyType` and add it to `ArtistType` like any other field.